# Why storing substrings may lead to memory leak in Swift?

Tags: swift, string, memory-leaks, substring, swift4

On Apple's documentation on [`Substring`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/substring#overview), is says:

> Don’t store substrings longer than you need them to perform a specific operation. A substring holds a reference to the entire storage of the string it comes from, not just to the portion it presents, even when there is no other reference to the original string. Storing substrings may, therefore, prolong the lifetime of string data that is no longer otherwise accessible, which can appear to be memory leakage.

I feel confused that `String` is a value type in Swift and how does it lead to memory leak?

Comment: `String` stores its contents indirectly in a (usually) reference-counted buffer. Being a value type doesn't prevent it from holding references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift Arrays, Sets, Dictionaries and Strings have value semantics, but they're actually copy-on-write wrappers for reference types. In other words, they're all `struct` wrappers around a `class`. This allows the following to work without making a copy:

```
let foo = "ABCDEFG"
let bar = foo
```

When you write to a `String`, it uses the standard library function `isUniquelyReferencedNonObjC` (unless it's been renamed again) to check if there are multiple references to the backing object. If so, it creates a copy before modifying it.

```
var foo = "ABCDEFG"
var bar = foo // no copy (yet)
bar += "HIJK" // backing object copied to keep foo and bar independent
```

When you use a Substring (or array slice), you get a reference to the entire backing object rather than just the bit that you want. This means that if you have a very large string and you have a substring of just 4 characters, as long as the substring is live, you're holding the entire string backing buffer in memory. This is the leak that this warns you about.

Comment: Thanks zneak. Your explanation is awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Given the way Swift is often portrayed your confusion is understandable. Types such as `String`, `Array` and `Dictionary` present value *semantics* but are library types constructed from a combination of value and references types.

The implementation of these types use dynamically allocated storage. This storage can be *shared* between different values. However library facilities are used to implement *copy-on-write* so that such shared storage is copied as needed to maintain value semantics, that is behaviour like that of value types.

HTH